# PostgreSQL ODBC Drivers on Windows 7 not showing up

Tags: postgresql, odbc

I'm running win7 64bit so I installed the (psqlodbc_09_00_0300-x64.zip) msi [64bit drivers for postgres odbc](http://www.postgresql.org/ftp/odbc/versions/msi/).

i also tried launching the odbc manager from the following location "%systemdrive%\Windows\SysWoW64\odbcad32.exe"

But i still don't see any postgres drivers i can use.

**Anyone know how to make them show up?**

[image]

Comment: Your screenshot shows a small part of the drivers list. If installed correctly the Postgres drivers should be way after all those "Microsoft ..." drivers.

Comment: Yeah, i wasn't able to resize the window... but i assure you they are not there. I just wanted to demonstrate where i couldn't see it.

Comment: I see them when I run "%windir%\system32\odbcad32.exe" ("Data Sources (ODBC)" from the "Administrative Tools") and I can't see them (unsurprisingly) when I run ""%systemdrive%\Windows\SysWoW64\odbcad32.exe", because it's the 32bit version of that tool. You could verify which is which in the task manager.

Comment: WoW64 stands for Windows-on-Windows 64. so which is the 64bit version?

Comment: `odbcad32.exe` on 64 bit Windows: `c:\windows\system32`: for 64 bit programs, `c:\windows\syswow64` for 32 bit programs.

Comment: The one in the system32 folder. The other one (in the syswow64 folder) is the [32bit version](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WoW64).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Setting up PostgreSQL ODBC on Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6796252/setting-up-postgresql-odbc-on-windows)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically in a case like this you want to install both the 64-bit drivers (for 64-bit programs) and the 32-bit drivers (for 32-bit programs).  If this doesn't work you have two options:

1. Uninstall and reinstall.  On reinstall disable antivirus software, etc. and anything else that may interfere with writing to the registry.
2. Run regsvr32 on on the 32-bit version and regsvr64 on the 64-bit version

Answer (score 3):

To setup DSN for 32-bit application you must use: %WINDIR%\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe
and for 64-bit application you must use: %WINDIR%\System32\odbcad32.exe

see http://psqlodbc.projects.pgfoundry.org/faq.html#6.8