# The latest Java that contains JDBC-ODBC

Tags: java, jdbc-odbc

Does anyone know what the most recent version of JDK and or JRE that contains the JDBC-ODBC bridge driver?

I have this jar that parses XML into Microsoft Access. I didn't realize the driver was removed when I was updating and now desperately trying to find a version that will let my jar work. I've tried JDK6u45 and that does allow my program to appear to run... as in no error and it will show a count of records that will be updated, but after considerable waiting nothing actually happens.

What's also strange is with this same build but on a different PC, the jar is giving me `[Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] '(unknown)' error.`

I'm pulling my hair out. Thanks in advance!

P.S. I'm aware of solutions that don't require JDBC-ODBC but currently, it looks like the source code may be lost too. So I really need a workaround now so I can make due until it's time to rewrite.

Comment: Java 1.7 is the last.

Comment: The error you're asking about indicates that the JVM did load the ODBC Driver... so I think you've got an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jdbc/bridge.html) Oracle doc it was removed starting with Java 8. So 7 or below should still contain the driver.

> The JDBC-ODBC Bridge should be considered a transitional solution; it will be removed in JDK 8.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14229072/removal-of-jdbc-odbc-bridge-in-java-8) stackoverflow discussion talks about the removal and possible alternative drivers.