# How to use hibernate with ms access?

Tags: java, hibernate, java-8, netbeans-8

I created a project in netbeans.
I required to connect ms access as DB using hibernate.
I also include some jars like...

commons-lang-2.6.jar 
commons-logging-1.1.3.jar 
hsqldb.jarhsqldb.jar 
jackcess-2.0.4.jar 
ucanaccess-2.0.8.jar

and I also create driver ODBC for ms access DB .
code for hibernate.cfg.xml.

```
<property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver</property>  
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=E:/mydb.accdb</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
```

but it show following errors.....

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.spi.ClassLoadingException: Unable to load class [sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver]
at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:245)   at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:245)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.loadDriverIfPossible(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:200)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.buildCreator(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:156)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:95)
```

Comment: What is the version of java you are using ?

Comment: See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22984438/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-sun-jdbc-odbc-jdbcodbcdriver-exception-occurin

Answer (score 0):

I think that the error message is clear:

```
Unable to load class [sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver]
```

Your program cannot find the class `sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver`.

The JDBC-ODBC-Bridge was deprecated and is removed in Java 8.

Comment: i also try it in jdk 7 but error is same

Comment: @dipenahir possibly you tried with a runtime rather than a JDK; only the JDK has the bridge driver jar.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use ODBC Bridge with Java8 Since it has been removed.

[Removal of JDBC ODBC bridge in java 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14229072/removal-of-jdbc-odbc-bridge-in-java-8)

Ref: [Oracle Blog Entry](https://blogs.oracle.com/Lance/entry/removal_of_the_jdbc_odbc)

Alternatively you will have to use a JDBC based driver for the same .