# Connect to third party database in SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

Recently downloaded Oracle 11g XE and Oracle SQL Developer. I want to migrate data from Access but when I follow the instructions to make a 3rd party connection only the Oracle tab appears in the connection window (unlike the 4 tabs in the video link below). Why is this and what can I do to resolve it?

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/migration/third-party-connection-1923525.html

Comment: ["No additional driver is required. Access uses the JDBC/ODBC bridge"](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/migration/jdbc-migration-1923524.html), but that [will be removed in JDK 8](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jdbc/bridge.html). If you're using SQL Developer 4.1 with JDK 8 then that may be why that tab isn't there. You could try a third-party driver (some are mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14229072/266304)) but it's not something I've tried.

Comment: Yes I am using SQL Developer 4.1 and JDK 8. So I can no longer migrate the Access data like I could before? Why have they done this? Will check out the 3rd party options. thx

Comment: Also see [this comment from Jeff Smith](http://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2012/01/sql-developer-supports-db2-sybase-mysql-access-and-teradata/comment-page-1/#comment-74523); might using an older version of SQL Developer and JDK just for the migration be an option for you?