# Connecting to Excel using JDBC 8

Tags: java, excel, jdbc

I've written a code that will be querying data from Excel using `odbc` bridge. Now since in java8 there is no more support to `odbc`, I'm searching an alternative of the same. I've nearly 32 different programs of suce. i.e. querying from Excel Database. Below is a sample program.

```
private void getTheDetailedDataForRca(String userName, XSSFWorkbook workbook, XSSFSheet sheet) {
        // System.out.println("ph2");
        try {
            DecimalFormat df2 = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
            HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Double>> myArray;
            myArray = new HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Double>>();
            String user = "%" + userName + "%";

            String dburl = path.getDBUrl();

            Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
            myConn = DriverManager.getConnection(dburl);
            String queryString = "select Error As Err, Sum(TotalErrors) as Errors from [Quality Sheet$] where Associate like ? group By Error";
            PreparedStatement ps = myConn.prepareStatement(queryString);
            ps.setString(1, user);
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
            myArray.put(userName, new HashMap<String, Double>());

            while (rs.next()) {
                double inputValue = rs.getDouble("Errors");
                String fin = df2.format(inputValue);
                myArray.get(userName).put(rs.getString("Err"), Double.parseDouble(fin));
            }
            ps.close();
            myConn.close();
            printMapOne(myArray, userName, workbook, sheet);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e + "\t" + "in finals sheet B2");
        }
    }
```

And my dburl is

```
public String getDBUrl() {
    return "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsm, *.xlsb)};DBQ=C:\\Users\\" + getSystemId
            + "\\Desktop\\Quality Sheets\\quality_template.xlsx;";
}
```

I checked it online and to my surprise I found nothing apart from suggesting to use `POI`. I tried with `UCanAccess`, but this supports only Access database. Can someone please let me know any alternate for `odbc`, so that I need not code the entire thing.

I've tried the solution given at [Removal of JDBC ODBC bridge in java 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14229072/removal-of-jdbc-odbc-bridge-in-java-8/36875001#36875001)

I got the message as below in cmd.

```
C:\Users\u0138039\Desktop\sun>jar -cvf jdbc.jar sun
sun : no such file or directory
added manifest
```

But a jar is created in folder.

I pasted the same jdbc driver in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre\lib` and copied `jdbcodbc.dll` to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_101\bin`, restarted and to my surprise I get the same `java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:odbc` Exception.

Thanks

Comment: See answer explaining [How to enable JDBC-ODBC bridge for JDK 8](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36875001/5221149)

Comment: Hi @Andreas, I tried this but unfortunately this happens not to work. Can you please take off the duplicate flag, I've searched this and then I've posted the question as I didn't find any other option :-(.

Comment: @Andreas, Also when I ran the command I got this message `C:\Users\u0138039\Desktop\sun>jar -cvf jdbc.jar sun
sun : no such file or directory
added manifest`. Can you please clarify if this is causing the error?

Comment: Do you have a `sun` folder inside the `sun` folder? If not, then maybe you need to be in the parent folder when running that command, in order to find the `sun` folder in the current folder.