# JAVA JDBC ODBC DRIVER SQLMX

Tags: java

I have an application that connect to mxsql(HP NON STOP DB) using ODBC DRIVER.
Below is the code :

```
 String driver = "sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver";
    String dbUrl = "jdbc:odbc:Smartvista";
    String dbUname = "*****";
    String dbPwd = "******";
    Class.forName(driver);
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbUrl, dbUname, dbPwd);
    String getQuery = "some query here";
    System.out.println(getQuery);
    Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
```

the code was working fine some time ago but stop working recently throwing below error

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
```

I suspect the error is related with java version. Some post has suggest using ucanacess , however i am unable to implement same.

Please advise anyone

Comment: Hi David,  i checked the post..i do not think it is related

Comment: Have you checked the classpaths?

Comment: There are quite a few questions already relating to similar error messages.Please check these first and if you like you can edit the question to show the steps you have already taken to resolve the issue

Comment: Hi David, indeed the issue was related with java version. JDBC is no longer supported in java 8. So alternatively i have forced my application to run with jre7

Comment: Glad that solved your issue! There are some workarounds [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14229072/5241933) as well