# Where to download sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver (trying to connect output csv from Spoon to SSMS)

Tags: ssms, pentaho, pentaho-spoon, data-integration

I have a csv that I have transformed in Kettle/Spoon/PDI and I am trying to output it to SSMS.

In Spoon, it's a two step process: read the csv (and edit a couple types), then output to SQL.

I get this error: "Driver class 'sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver' could not be found, make sure the 'MS SQL Server' driver (jar file) is installed.
sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver"

I can't seem to find where to download this driver.  (Have googled it obviously, though perhaps not enough.)

Comment: Add this driver to "lib" folder of your pdi and restart spoon

Answer (score 0):

I think the fact is not specific related to pentaho, else, to Java. The native connection type for java is JDBC, since Java 8, ODBC support was removed, so you may need jdbc2odbc bridge driver to connect ODBC datasources, but as far as I know, the only working solution is not open.

You can see more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14229072/removal-of-jdbc-odbc-bridge-in-java-8/).

Answer (score 0):

http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/jdbc/jdbc.jar.zip

link to download sun.jdbc.odbc.jdbcodbcdriver jar file

Comment: is that for java to ms access?

Comment: sun.jdbc.odbc.jdbcodbcdriver not available

Comment: That is the mysql jdbc driver