# Java ODBC connection with Excel driver

Tags: java, excel, odbc

I have an ODBC connection set up with an Excel driver. How to set up this connection in a Java project in order to be able to perform SQL queries?

Answer (score 1):

Java doesn't work directly with ODBC.

You have two possibilities :

1. Use a odbc-jdbc bridge like said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51732371/where-to-download-sun-jdbc-odbc-jdbcodbcdriver-trying-to-connect-output-csv-fro) and [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jdbc/bridge.html#:%7E:text=The%20JDBC%2DODBC%20Bridge%20allows,jdbc.).
2. Use a library dedicated to Excel manipulation like [Apache poi](https://poi.apache.org/).