# How to use .csv as read-only database in Java 8 (as It can't be done with ODBC)?

Tags: database, csv, java-8, odbc

How can *csv* be used as a read-only database without a JDBC-ODBC bridge in java 8?

I am getting this error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver
```

Comment: How do you use your datasource? Only as read-only database?

Comment: See here for some suggestions: https://stackoverflow.com/q/14229072

Comment: Reformatted to make your question easier to read. Still, your input is pretty unclear. CSV is nothing but a file format, and it isn't really related to databases. Whereas the exception you have here points to a missing database driver. Thus: please read [mcve] and further enhance your question.

Comment: @Flown yes only as read-only database

Comment: Then have a look at: http://csvjdbc.sourceforge.net/

Comment: 3rd party JDBC-ODBC bridge: [cdata.com/drivers/bridge/jdbc/](https://www.cdata.com/drivers/bridge/jdbc/) and 3rd party JDBC Driver for CSV: [cdata.com/drivers/csv/jdbc](https://www.cdata.com/drivers/csv/jdbc). _Full Disclosure: my employer_

Answer (score 0):

You could use a database such as h2 to load the CSV file as a table or directly read using its utilities.
Look into http://h2database.com/html/tutorial.html#csv