# how do we convert JSON object to Result set in JAVA

Tags: json, resultset

we are reading excel data using JDBC ODBC bridge ,we want to upgrade to JAVA 8. But Java 8 doesn't support JDBC ODBC bridge, it's removed.
Have huge legacy code which expects Resultset to process the data, we are looking for different options to get final object in resultset type.
We tried converting the Excel file to json object, is there anyway to convert json object to resultset?
Please suggest any otherways, final objective is it should be in form of resultset

Comment: Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14229072/removal-of-jdbc-odbc-bridge-in-java-8

Comment: @DavidLukas first of all thanks for sharing info.

Comment: Tried the both solution none of them is working , replacing file from the older version to latest version.

Comment: Ucanaccess can we used only for Ms access related files , it won't work for excel files.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Removal of JDBC ODBC bridge in java 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14229072/removal-of-jdbc-odbc-bridge-in-java-8)