# Connecting to PostGreSQL through Microsoft Access 2019

Tags: postgresql, ms-access

We have a need to connect to a PG database using Microsoft Access 2018.
I downloaded the [ODBC driver](https://www.postgresql.org/ftp/odbc/versions/msi/) ( psqlodbc_12_01_0000-x64.zip). I made sure the driver was also added to the system path in environment variables ( `C:\Program Files\psqlODBC\1201\bin`) for both the user and the system. I then restarted my computer.

I checked the OBDC Drive in Admin and the drivers are listed.
[image]

I do have a 64-bit OS

[image]

When I try to make a connection to it in Microsoft Access ( **External Data > New Data Source > Select Data Source > Machine Data Source > New**) it doesn't appear as an option to connect to. What am I missing here?

Comment: Do you have 64 bit access? OS is not important, if you have 32 bit office, you'll need a 32 bit odbc driver

Comment: @Steeeve - yes. I've updated the OP to have this info

Comment: @reactFullStackDeveloper You can run 32 bit access on a 64 bit OS (for a long time this was the default). Check in the [About Access](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/about-office-what-version-of-office-am-i-using-932788b8-a3ce-44bf-bb09-e334518b8b19) dialog (this will state 32-bit or 64-bit).

Comment: Yep - I just read this comment from a previous post [https://stackoverflow.com/a/12072056/6477047] - that was it. Access on my machine is 32 bit so I needed to 32 bit PG driver. Thank you